# Configure websphere httpd.conf and plugin-cfg.xml

Tags: websphere, httpd.conf, ibmhttpserver

i have an application which is deployed on websphere application server with ibm http server.I want to change the domain name.I have figured out that changes will be required in httpd.conf file. in the servername tag.also plugin-cfg.xml needs to be changed.How should i modify these files.and how will the changes be reflected.
And are there any other files/properties files where i have to chnage the domain name.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to edit plugin-cfg.xml manually (except in very rare cases). The hostnames in there come from the Aliases defined for the WebSphere Virtual Hosts.

By default, those usually have *:80, so changing the server domain name would require no changes at all. For instance:

```
<VirtualHostGroup Name="default_host">
  <VirtualHost Name="*:9080"/>
  <VirtualHost Name="*:80"/>
  <VirtualHost Name="*:9443"/>
  <VirtualHost Name="*:5060"/>
  <VirtualHost Name="*:5061"/>
  <VirtualHost Name="*:443"/>
</VirtualHostGroup>
```

If the WebSphere Virtual Host that your application is using does specify an Alias with a particular domain name, you just change the domain name there.

Comment: @dbrequx  How would I add a new Uri to a URI group of the plugin-cfg.xml file (without editing it manually)  either using web console or the scripting console?

Comment: @Chandu Isn't that really a whole new question? But in general, most things in that file can be edited through more permanent means. Like the console (or scripting). Or in this case, Uris come from patterns in your application's web.xml

Comment: Thanks. I will elaborate my question and post it as such

Comment: Posted my question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33173151/websphere-how-to-add-a-uri-to-urigroup-of-plugin-cfg-xml