# Websphere: How to add a Uri to UriGroup of plugin-cfg.xml

Tags: websphere

I am new to Websphere.
We have installed a simple hello world app on the websphere application server (8.5.5) and with ibm http server with the context root set as /HelloWorld.
Given below is the web.xml we are using for the war:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>HelloWorld</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>welcome</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>welcome</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

When I browse to http:///HelloWorld I am expecting to see the contents of the index.jsp page of my hello world application.
However I am getting the "Forbidden" page. I see the contents if I use the path  http:///HelloWorld/index.jsp

Some posts/documentation online lead me to plugin-cfg.xml file on the server.
I have edited the file to add the Uri "/HelloWorld/*" to the default URIGroup manually and it works.

Now my question is how do I add a Uri to the UriGroup using the Adminsitration Console?
Also is there a way to have the route added via the war being deployed instead of editing the plugin-cfg file explicitly.

**Update:**
It's working now I assumed that mapping the module to the Cluster during deployment ("Map modules to servers" step) will automatically map it to the web server, but apparently not. I have mapped the module to the cluster and the web server and it works I will just redo the whole deployment from scratch again to make sure my understanding is correct and then update the post.

Thanks @dbreaux

**Update#1**

I guess I should RTFI (I = Instruction). The fix for my issue was right there on the deployment page.

> **Map modules to servers**
>   Specify targets such as application servers
>   or clusters of application servers where you want to install the
>   modules that are contained in your application. Modules can be
>   installed on the same application server or dispersed among several
>   application servers. **Also, specify the Web servers as targets that
>   **serve as routers for requests to this application. The plug-in
>   **configuration file (plugin-cfg.xml) for each Web server is generated,
>   based on the applications that are routed through.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first, this should be handled by `web.xml` for certain, not by editing `plugin-cfg.xml`.

I suspect if you change your `<url-pattern>` to '/*', it will work as you expect. But I'd have expected '/' to work as well, as that's the "default" mapping. See [Difference between / and /* in servlet mapping url pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/difference-between-and-in-servlet-mapping-url-pattern)

Depending on what you're trying to do, though, there might be more normal ways to do it. For instance, `web.xml` provides a `<welcome-file-list>` element where you define what URL you want provided when the plain context-root is requested.

You also don't need to explicitly define `<servlet>` elements for JSPs at all. Those are understood automatically by WebSphere.

So in your case, this should be sufficient:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>HelloWorld</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Thanks I will try the config you mentioned. However I noticed that when I generate the plugin-cfg file it gets generated with some default Uri in uriGroup like /snoop/, /hello/ etc. Where would these be coming from?

Comment: Sounds like you have the default application installed as well. One for testing with.

Comment: Yes. I would like to know what config in web.xml (if at all) of those wars is resulting in the generation of the Url /snoop etc .

Comment: It's not in your web.xml, it's a whole separate ear/war installed into WAS. Look at the WAS console and see if there's another application installed. See https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rweb_defapp.html

Comment: Thanks I am aware of the default ear/war. Am not clear how the entries ` <Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/snoop/*"/>` are getting added when I generate the plugin-cfg file

Comment: They get added by that default ear/war. plugin-cfg has entries for all installed applications. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're asking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92523/discussion-between-chandu-and-dbreaux).

Comment: It's working now
I assumed that mapping the module to the Cluster during deployment ("Map modules to servers" step) will automatically map it to the web server, but apparently not. I have mapped the module to the cluster and the web server and it works
I will just redo the whole deployment from scratch again to make sure my understanding is correct and then update the post.

Comment: OOPS ... I was using my phone while upvoting and looks light I hit the down arrow. It doesn't let me change my vote now, unless the answer is edited. Can you you do a dummy edit so that I can revert my vote?